# Превратить некоторые строки в столбцы

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

В общем, есть запрос, в этом запросе через `CROSS APPLY` я вызываю табличную функцию, которая на каждую строчку возвращает 4 записи- сплитит по "," строковое поле с 4 координатами.

Могу ли я как-нибудь эти возвращаемые 4 строки превратить в 4 колонки в результирующем запросе?

Comment: развернуть их обычным образом: group by и функции вроде `max(case when x=1 then y else NULL end)`

Comment: Вроде, получилось добиться желаемого результата через PIVOT и ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось добиться желаемого результата через `PIVOT` и `ROW_Number`.

В под запросе `PIVOT` я вызвал `ROW_Number` с `Partition by ID`, тем самым я пронумеровал каждую строчку внутри группы от 1 до 4 в рамках ID.

Далее внутри Pivot я передал результат `Row_number` в параметр, который отвечает за столбец, который содержит заголовки и получил нужный мне результат.

```
SELECT 
id,[1],[2],[3],[4]
 FROM 
(
SELECT id,a
ROW_Number() OVER (Partition by id order by (select null)) as Col
  FROM InnerTable
CROSS APPLY   [какая-то табличная функция, которая возвращает 4 строки на запись] a
) as t
PIVOT(
max(a) FOR Col IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as PivotTable
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо проиллюстрировать вопрос и ответ примерами данных, так сказать для наглядности.

Comment: Добавил скрипт.